# Angularjs and vimeo api: iframe displaying as string instead of iframe

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, vimeo-api

I have my vimeo api that i fetch using angularjs or angular2.

Everything works great except the iframe.

I use {{data.embed.html}} to display the iframe but displays the iframe as string, not the video

This is my video.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of lenght; let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let video of videos">
    <ul>
      <li>{{video.data[i].embed.html}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is what I get instead of getting the real video. It works great if i do it in a regular ajax get request in javascript, but I cannot make it work in any angular version.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [innerHtml] directive.

```
<li [innerHtml]="video.data[i].embed.html"></li>
```

More about it in [Angular2 guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. That works!! I had to sanitize it but now is working. I have no idea how I could not find this before.